# Xpage button not running server side script

Tags: fullcalendar, xpages

Short Description: Fullcalendar seems to prevent server side javascript in buttons from executing.

Long Description:

I am running fullcalendar.io in a Domino application. The calendar is run in an XPage.
I have another XPage with navigation buttons that is opening this XPage.

When opening the calendar Xpage and switching between months and weeks everything is fine. But after paging forward or backward a couple of times in the calendar. Then pressing a button in the navigation menu it runs the client side code in the buttton. But then only refreshes the page. It doees not run the server side code.

(Both switching between months and Weeks and pressing back/ forward generates ajax requests to server
Fullcalendar never stops working it only prevents other buttons from working
)

Links in the navigation menu work fine. Just buttons. I'm suspecting it has something to do with fullcalendar blocking other ajax requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This have to do with the how many pages your site is set to store in memory or on disk. You can increase this is xsp.properties, I believe 16 is default in 9.0.1 and less in previous versions

xsp.persistence.tree.maxviews=16

[image]

I think you need to do "Project Clean" if you change this setting and want to see immediate results

Comment: Excellent!! That solved it. How on earth did you connect the problem to that setting ?

Comment: Tack kommer du till Hötorget bjuder jag på lunch !!